# Can I change phpMyAdmin's default queries?

Tags: count, phpmyadmin

I have several large innodb tables (over 500M records). When I click on one to view it, the system takes forever (a couple minutes) to return the first 30 rows. I went into my shell program and saw that phpMyAdmin was doing a select count(*) from table. This DIES in innodb. I do have the table indexed by the primary key which is an auto-increment id.

Is there any way to change this so that phpMyAdmin is actually useful for large innoDB tables? It worked fine for myIsam as count(*) performs well there. With innodb you need to count an indexed column, such as count(id).

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: This is an outdated version, try updating.

Comment: The newest version is 4.4.15.5, released on 2016-02-29. (I left out the .15 in mine) 

Are you saying you have re-written that part in the last month? Or are you just guessing? Do you KNOW that issue was fixed that recently?

Comment: I don't know if this was fixed, but reporting an issue on an outdated version won't get you very far. By the way your 4.4.5 was released on 2015-05-05 and its security issues fixed meanwhile probably do not include a performance fix.

Comment: Also, which database server are you using (including the version number) ?

Comment: Figured it out. I was running a very old version, not the one I thought. Re-installing the latest on Mysql 5.7 now. I'll report back if that has the same problem.

Comment: According to https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/milestones version 4.6.0 is due on March 22. Please also report back if the newer version fixes your problem.

Comment: Yes, it did. I am all set now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your phpMyAdmin version if it's outdated.